# Entity Framework and AutoMapper - how insert or update relations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, entity-relationship

I'm working on a Web API project structured as 3-tier application that uses Entity Framework for data access:

- Controller, consumed by UI
- Business Logic (BLL), business operations (as log and other)
- Repository (DAL), the only one that access to Entity Framework context

I use AutoMapper for mapping entities to DTOs and vice-versa.

Here is some code:

**DTO**

```
public class RoleDTO
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<UserDTO> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserDTO
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<RoleDTO> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

**DAL**

```
public IEnumerable<RoleDTO> GetRoles()
{
    var entities = Context.Roles.AsEnumerable();

    return DTOMapper<IEnumerable<RoleDTO>>(entities);
}
```

**BLL**

```
public IEnumerable<RoleDTO> GetRoles()
{
    return Repository.GetRoles();
}
```

All worked until now. Suppose that `Roles` and `Users` have a many-to-many relationship. I have to insert a **new** role and attach to it some **existing** user. So I pass to DAL the `RoleDTO` and map it to `Role` that has a `Users` collection. When I call `SaveChanges()` I get a PK violation because Entity Framework is trying to insert the related users but they already exists.

How can I resolve it?